# Apply styles based upon javascript condition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two separate `<style>` tags which both contain a large number of styles and media queries. The first set of styles is applied for desktop viewers, the other set is applied for mobile viewers. When both sets of media queries run, it messes up the display because different components are visible at different sizes. I had been dynamically linking style sheets based upon the user display, but I have been asked to do it all on one page with no additional file loading. Is there any way I can apply one set of styles or the other exclusively via javascript?

Comment: If you must detect "mobile" devices this way, consider setting a base class right on your `<body>` element.

Comment: The <style> tags contain dozens of different styles applied to as many objects and multiple media queries. I have assigned styles to child elements but never media queries. Can it still be done this way?

Comment: For this method, you'll need to modify your CSS, prepending the class to each relevant rule.  If you're using something like LESS/SASS, this is easy.  Otherwise, copy/paste doesn't take too long.

Comment: I would have to have 3 conditionals or so for almost every class, probably quite a mess.  TY for the LESS/SASS, there may be a work around in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a mobile detection in JavaScript then add a class depending on which styles you want. ie.

```
<body>
  <div class="mobile">
    .. your page ..
  </div>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
  <div class="desktop">
    .. your page ..
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just throw that class right on the `<body>`.   No need for an additional element.

Comment: The `<style>` tags contain dozens of different styles applied to as many objects and multiple media queries.  I have assigned styles to child elements but never media queries.  Can it still be done this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can link it within your CSS links

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 701px)' href='css/medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 702px)' href='css/large.css' />
```